# C#: Прямой доступ + cookiecontainer

Tags: c#

Кароче, что-то я промучился и ничего не получилось.
Сделал вот что:
Создал у себя на сайте login.php:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $lg = "admin";
    $ps = "test";

    if ($login == $lg)
    {
        if ($password == $ps)
        {
            $_SESSION['logged'] = $password;
            header('Location: http://d7support.500mb.net/home.php');
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Password Incorrect";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Login Incorrect";
    }

?>
```

И home.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])) 
    {
        echo "Tut Kaptcha";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "nihera ne pawet!";
    }

?>
```

Тут все просто, если в login.php все сработало то нас переадресовало на home.php.

И так, вот в чем проблема.
Вот код запроса на login.php:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data = "login=admin&password=test";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://d7support.500mb.net/login.php");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] EncodedPostParams = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams, 0, EncodedPostParams.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Close();

            CookieContainer authInfo = new CookieContainer();
            request.CookieContainer = authInfo;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            authInfo = request.CookieContainer;

            string html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            showInfoBox.AppendText(html);
        }
```

Тоесть я получил данные о авторизации в cookiecontainer и прошло все как нужно.

*Теперь я хочу стразу сделать запрос на home.php использовав имеющиеся данные у меня в `cookiecontainer`, и я делаю вот так:*

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest qq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://d7support.500mb.net/home.php");
            qq.CookieContainer = authInfo;
            HttpWebResponse tt = (HttpWebResponse)qq.GetResponse();
            string zz = new StreamReader(tt.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            showJobBox.AppendText(zz);
        }
```

И все, не работает, тоесть имея данные авторизации я немогу зайти напрямую на home.php?

Почему? Подскажите что не так?

И вообще как просмотреть имеется ли у меня чтото в cookiecontainer?

Comment: Быть может чтобы Вам было проще, то вот мой проект: http://depositfiles.com/files/l57afndqo

Comment: http://www.heroeswm.ru/ вот сайт. чтобы вы не регистрировались у меня есть тестовый аккаунт: ЛОГИН: D7test ПАРОЛЬ: qqqAAA И так, после авторизации нужно сделать запрос на страницу: http://www.heroeswm.ru/home.php и http://www.heroeswm.ru/map.php ну тоесть мне должно вернуть исходный код этих страниц. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Я немного поправил и теперь вот что...
Закоментировал строку:
home.AllowAutoRedirect = false; - ну тоесть чтобы переадресация срабатывала. После этого я получаю данные от index.php значит что меня передресовало на Главную страницу, а переадресовало из-за того что данные авторизации CookieContainer несработали при запросе к home.php. Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Протестировал Ваш код, все работает. При повторном запросе на home.php возвращает "Tut Kaptcha". Вы уверенны, что при запросе на home.php передаете именно тот CookieContainer, который был сохранен ранее?

По поводу того, как посмотреть, что в CookieContainer:

```
CookieCollection cookies = authInfo.GetCookies(new Uri("http://d7support.500mb.net"));
```

Ну а с коллекцией думаю разберетесь.

Comment: немогли бы вы скинуть свой код, я все перепроверил но всеравно не пашет у меня.

Comment: да, все работает.

Comment: хорошо) только что увидел комментарий. проект думаю уже не нужно скидывать?

Comment: есть еще маленькая просьба немного обьяснить...
Мой код работает для моего варианта. Но я просто делаюпод другой сайт, а это у меня как пример. Так вот, я аналогично отправляю запрос на тот другой сайт и он мне вообще ничего не возвращает. 
Я думал что может там дополнительная связка с login.php но если в браузере авторизироватся нормально, потом просто вставить ссылку в новой вкладке на home.php она открывается, значит в браузере сохранилось то что нужно и работает. Так почему же у меня не работает, що еще может сохранить браузер что не сохранило cokiecontainer?

Comment: уточните, что за сайт. думаю у Вас просто неправильно выстроен сам запрос на сервер.

Comment: http://www.heroeswm.ru/
вот сайт. чтобы вы не регистрировались у меня есть тестовый аккаунт: ЛОГИН: D7test ПАРОЛЬ: qqqAAA И так, после авторизации нужно сделать запрос на страницу: http://www.heroeswm.ru/home.php и http://www.heroeswm.ru/map.php ну тоесть мне должно вернуть исходный код этих страниц. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: посмотрел.. но понять в чем причина не могу.